# Android Deeplink how to use existing Activity for handle Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I have an activity which display celebrity and some information.

Declaration in manifest :

```
  <activity
            android:name=".CelebrityActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_celebrities"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="some_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) :

> For example, the command below tries to view a target app activity that is associated with the specified URI.

```
 $ adb shell am start
    -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
    -d "example://gizmos" com.example.android
```

My problem it was when i execute **adb command**(which you see above) it recreates my Activity always, even activity is launched.

I try to add `launchMode:singleInstance` flag, but... no changes. Activity also recreates.

So my question is **how to handle result in existing Activity**?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use

```
adb shell am broadcast -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "some_scheme://"
```

instead of `adb shell am start`. Links are handled as a broadcast by the android framework.